# Understanding make error message

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, sfml

So, I cloned SqAtx's GitHub repository [SuperMarioWorld](https://github.com/SqAtx/SuperMarioWorld) onto my Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) machine. I would like to run his Super Mario clone in order to understand his project and learn by the way he did this game.

First of all, I could not compile it as he explained it in the README.md. However, I have successfully compiled an own Battleship game the same way (which tells me Cmake, make, SFML, and a C compiler are correctly installed). As an error I got this error message after running `cmake ..` from the build folder:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
 add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


 -- Found SFML 2.4.0 in /usr/include
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:32 (target_link_libraries):
 Cannot specify link libraries for target "SuperMarioWorld" which is not
 built by this project.


 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I then modified his CMakeList.txt so that it successfully creates a makefile. My CMakeList.txt looks as follows:

```
#Change this if you need to target a specific CMake version
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)  

# Enable debug symbols by default
# must be done before project() statement
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)  
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build (Debug or Release)" FORCE)  
endif()  

project (SuperMarioWorld)  

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --std=c++11 -Wall -g")  

# I guess you have not released the project yet :p
set (SuperMarioWorld_VERSION_MAJOR 0)  
set (SuperMarioWorld_VERSION_MINOR 1)  
set (SuperMarioWorld_VERSION_PATCH 0)  

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")  
set(SOURCE_FILES  
    EventEngine/Listeners/CharacterDiedListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/CharacterPositionUpdateListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/CloseRequestListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/DebugInfoUpdatedListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/ForegroundItemRemovedListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/ForegroundItemUpdatedListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/GotLevelInfoListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/KeyboardListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/LevelStartListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/MarioJumpListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/MarioKickedEnemyListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/NewCharacterReadListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/NewForegroundItemReadListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/NewPipeReadListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/Listeners/ToggleIgnoreInputListener.cpp  
    EventEngine/EventEngine.cpp  
    Game/CollisionHandler.cpp  
    Game/GameEngine.cpp  
    Game/LevelImporter.cpp  
    Graphics/GraphicsEngine.cpp  
    Graphics/SpriteHandler.cpp  
    Sound/SoundEngine.cpp  
    SuperMario/Game.cpp  
    SuperMario/main.cpp  
    System/Characters/Enemy.cpp  
    System/Characters/Goomba.cpp  
    System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp  
    System/Characters/Player.cpp  
    System/Items/Box.cpp  
    System/Items/Pipe.cpp  
    System/irrXML/irrXML.cpp  
    System/Engine.cpp  
    System/Util.cpp  
)  
# Define sources and executable
set (EXECUTABLE_NAME "SuperMarioWorld")  
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})  

# Detect and add SFML
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})  
#Find any version 2.X of SFML
#See the FindSFML.cmake file for additional details and instructions
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)  
if(SFML_FOUND)  
  include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})  
  target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})  
endif()  

# Install target
install(TARGETS ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} DESTINATION bin)
```

With this CMakeList.txt I could successfully create a makefile. Running the make I first got two errors which where the same:

```
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/EventEngine/Listeners/NewForegroundItemReadListener.cpp:21:95: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
m_graphicsEngine->UpdateForegroundItem(&(_event->GetDisplayableObject()->GetInfoForDisplay()));
```

So I had to fix it in `NewPipeReadListener.cpp` on line 24 and in `NewForegroundItemReadListener.cpp` on line 24. I fixed it like this:

```
InfoForDisplay temp = _event->GetPipe()->GetInfoForDisplay();
m_graphicsEngine->UpdateForegroundItem(&temp);
```

Now, the makefile gives me an error I cannot fix, since I don't understand a word.. I would like to include the whole error message here, but Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do so...
But it starts like this.

```
[  2%] Linking CXX executable SuperMarioWorld
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/EventEngine/Listeners/KeyboardListener.cpp.o: In function `KeyboardListener::onEvent(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Event*)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/EventEngine/Listeners/KeyboardListener.cpp:12: undefined reference to `KeyboardEvent::GetType()'
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/EventEngine/Listeners/KeyboardListener.cpp:13: undefined reference to `KeyboardEvent::GetKey()'
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/EventEngine/Listeners/KeyboardListener.cpp:14: undefined reference to `KeyboardEvent::GetType()'
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/EventEngine/Listeners/KeyboardListener.cpp:15: undefined reference to `KeyboardEvent::GetKey()'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp.o: In function `CollisionHandler::HandleCollisionsWithMapEdges(MovingObject&)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp:25: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::GetCoordinates() const'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp.o: In function `CollisionHandler::DetectCollisionWithObj(MovingObject&, DisplayableObject&)':
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me understand this error and possibly make the project run on my system.

EDIT:
After fixing the the first error which was including `EventEngine/KeyboardEvent.cpp` it links up to a 100% and spits out the following error message:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable SuperMarioWorld
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp.o: In function `CollisionHandler::HandleCollisionsWithMapEdges(MovingObject&)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp:25: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::GetCoordinates() const'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp.o: In function `CollisionHandler::DetectCollisionWithObj(MovingObject&, DisplayableObject&)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp:40: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::GetCoordinates() const'
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp:40: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::GetCoordinates() const'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp.o: In function `CollisionHandler::ReactToCollisionsWithObj(MovingObject&, DisplayableObject&, CollisionDirection)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp:45: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::GetCoordinates() const'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp.o: In function `CollisionHandler::HandleCollisionWithRect(unsigned int, sf::Rect<float>)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp:73: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::GetCoordinates() const'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp.o:/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/Game/CollisionHandler.cpp:138: more undefined references to `DisplayableObject::GetCoordinates() const' follow
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/Game/GameEngine.cpp.o: In function `GameEngine::UpdateForegroundItem(unsigned int, sf::Rect<float>)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/Game/GameEngine.cpp:114: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::SetCoordinates(sf::Rect<float>)'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/Game/LevelImporter.cpp.o: In function `LevelImporter::StoreFloor()':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/Game/LevelImporter.cpp:180: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::DisplayableObject(EventEngine*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, sf::Vector2<float>, State)'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp.o: In function `MovingObject::MovingObject(EventEngine*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, sf::Vector2<float>, State)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp:5: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::DisplayableObject(EventEngine*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, sf::Vector2<float>, State)'
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp:5: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::~DisplayableObject()'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp.o: In function `MovingObject::MovingObject(EventEngine*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, float, float, State)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp:10: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::DisplayableObject(EventEngine*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, float, float, State)'
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp:10: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::~DisplayableObject()'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp.o: In function `MovingObject::~MovingObject()':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp:25: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::~DisplayableObject()'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp.o: In function `MovingObject::GetInfoForDisplay()':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp:32: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::GetInfoForDisplay()'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Characters/MovingObject.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI12MovingObject[_ZTI12MovingObject]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for DisplayableObject'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Box.cpp.o: In function `Box::Box(EventEngine*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, sf::Vector2<float>, State)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Items/Box.cpp:3: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::DisplayableObject(EventEngine*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, sf::Vector2<float>, State)'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Box.cpp.o: In function `Box::Box(EventEngine*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, float, float, State)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Items/Box.cpp:8: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::DisplayableObject(EventEngine*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, float, float, State)'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Box.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV3Box[_ZTV3Box]+0x20): undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::GetInfoForDisplay()'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Box.cpp.o: In function `Box::~Box()':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Items/Box.hpp:9: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::~DisplayableObject()'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Box.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI3Box[_ZTI3Box]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for DisplayableObject'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Pipe.cpp.o: In function `Pipe::Pipe(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, sf::Vector2<float>, int, PipeType, EventEngine*)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Items/Pipe.cpp:5: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::DisplayableObject(EventEngine*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, sf::Vector2<float>, State)'
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Items/Pipe.cpp:5: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::~DisplayableObject()'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Pipe.cpp.o: In function `Pipe::~Pipe()':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Items/Pipe.cpp:14: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::~DisplayableObject()'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Pipe.cpp.o: In function `Pipe::SpawnEnemyIfTimeElapsed()':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Items/Pipe.cpp:50: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::DisplayableObject(EventEngine*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, float, float, State)'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Pipe.cpp.o: In function `Pipe::MoveEnemyBeingSpawned(float)':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Items/Pipe.cpp:58: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::Slide(float, float)'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Pipe.cpp.o: In function `Pipe::IsEnemyReadyToLeavePipe()':
/home/lex/Documents/cs/games/SuperMarioWorld/System/Items/Pipe.cpp:92: undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::GetCoordinates() const'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Pipe.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV4Pipe[_ZTV4Pipe]+0x20): undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::GetInfoForDisplay()'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Pipe.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV4Pipe[_ZTV4Pipe]+0x28): undefined reference to `DisplayableObject::UpdateAfterCollision(CollisionDirection, ObjectClass)'
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/System/Items/Pipe.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI4Pipe[_ZTI4Pipe]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for DisplayableObject'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/build.make:957: recipe for target 'SuperMarioWorld' failed
make[2]: *** [SuperMarioWorld] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SuperMarioWorld.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

EDIT2:
Now, I feel stupid, there was another file I forgot to include, it was `System/DisplayableObject.cpp`.

Thanks, everyone for the help!!!

Comment: Error "undefined reference" means that function is *declared* (in some header file) but **not defined** (there is no code for it). E.g., code for `KeyboardEvent::GetKey()` function is contained in the source file `EventEngine/KeyboardEvent.cpp`, but you don't compile it.

Comment: As for question text formatting, you use symbol '>' which is for *quotations*. Code formatting is achived by starting the line with 4 spaces, or using tool `{}` on the selected text. Same for error logs.

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem for part of it. I updated the Question now. Also thanks for the tip with the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include all the source files in the build.

For instance, in your error message the linker is complaining that it is missing the definition for the `KeyboardEvent::GetType()` function.

Searching the repo on github for `KeyboardEvent` will quickly tell you that this function is defined in `EventEngine/KeyboardEvent.cpp`, which is not part of your CMake's `SOURCE_FILES`.

You might be missing other source files as well. Try fixing the linker errors one by one until it compiles.

Comment: Thanks, that solved a big part of my problem! It was actually the only source file I missed.
Status of compilation is now 100% but it still spits out an error after that.